# Python: Indexing in Pandas with Datetime indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I've got problems regarding to indexing in Pandas and hope you can help me:

```py
rng = pd.date_range('2015-12-31 21:00:00', periods=7, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Val' : np.random.randn(len(rng)) }, index=rng) 
first_value_of_year = df['2016'].first('1H').index
```

returns the first value of the year as DatetimeIndex:

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

When I call the dataframe with this index, everything seems to be working fine:

```py
df.loc[first_value_of_year]
```

returns

```
+------------------------+-----------+
|                        |  Val      |
+------------------------+-----------+
| 2016-01-01             | 0.144044  |
```

So, everything is OK up to here!
But if I want to get all values greater than this value, it doesn't work anymore:

```py
df.loc[df.index >= first_value_of_year]
```

and gives ValueError (lenghts must match):

but if I take the same command with the timestamp itself as string it does what it should do

```py
df.loc[df.index >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00']
```

returns

```
+------------------------+-----------+
|                        |  Val      |
+------------------------+-----------+
| 2016-01-01 01:00:00    | 1.454274  |
| 2016-01-01 02:00:00    | 0.761038  |
| 2016-01-01 03:00:00    | 0.121675  |
```

so, what am I missing here? How do I correctly access all values greater than the DatetimeIndex variable?

Thanks!

Comment: I could not understand if it works the way you want or not? Also, printing the type of variables inside the square brackets may give you a hint, e.g. print(type(df.index >= first_value_of_year))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need select first value of index to scalar by indexing - `[0]`:

```
df.loc[df.index >= first_value_of_year[0]]
```

Comment: thank you so much... have spent over 2 hours on this :-)